# Dynamically changing the title of a final JRadioButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jradiobutton

I'm having this problem where I can't figure out how to update the name of my JRadioButtons

I've set them up in the contsructor like so:

```
final JRadioButton ANSWER1 = new JRadioButton(answer1);
```

with answer1 being a String.

but whenever i change answer1, the name of the JRadioButton doesn't change.

I've set the JRadioButton to change name at the event of a JButton being clicked:

```
NEXT.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    qnumber++;
    answer1 = "blah blah";
    ANSWER1.setText(answer1);
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're having a shadowing or context issue...

Comment: Bit of a beginner, what does that mean?

Comment: @chrispbacon what is the datatype of answer1 ?

Comment: Can you post the full code for this? Also, make sure you're getting into that `actionPerformed` method by placing a breakpoint.

Comment: What you think you're changing is what you actually want to change

Answer (score 1):

```
final JRadioButton ANSWER1 = new JRadioButton(answer1);
```

should be (search for Java naming conventions)

```
final JRadioButton answer1 = new JRadioButton(ANSWER1);
```

---

- whatever hidden in `String value answer1` (this variable should be defined as `constant` - `private String ANSWER1`) can be used for `setName`, `setActionCommand`, `putClientProperty` or descriptor for `Swing Action`, you can returns this value from every `AWT/Swing Listeners` added to `JRadioButton`

---

- use `JLabel` for displaying narrative on the screen, you can to chains the `JLabel` with `JRadioButton` by using [setLabelFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setLabelFor%28java.awt.Component%29)

---

- use `ItemListener` for `JRadioButton`, test for `SELECTED`/`DESELECTED` instead of `ActionListener`